# Is scanning via source ports still relevant/advised?

Tags: penetration-test

Does it still make sense to scan using a source port with Nmap when doing host or service discovery?

This would have made sense back in the day, but with statefull firewalls being prevalent, where source port scanning would not help, does it make sense to do source port scanning as part of a penetration test to help in discovery?

Or to put it simpler, does source port scanning have a place in a modern penetration testing methodology?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it's worth trying.**

1. It doesn't add much time or effort just to try the commonly used source ports.
2. There are still plenty of people running old or inappropriate devices as "firewalls".
3. No matter how shiny and stateful a firewall is, it has no defense against an administrator who opens by source port because they learned it that way (on a Cisco router, no doubt) or because they cut and paste something they found on Google.

Seriously, don't discount #3.  I worked with a Check Point administrator - 90% of his job was Check Point - who dutifully created two rules which bidirectionally mirrored each other whenever access was asked for.  He simply did not understand what stateful meant, and he kept writing things that looked like router ACLs, no matter how many times I came over after security review and said "This does not do what you think it does."